# How to include a vuejs webpack cli app in laravel

Tags: webpack, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel 5.4 application and a separate vuejs 2 application created with the webpack cli. I now want to add the vuejs project into my laravel project but want to keep things like HotModuleReloading and all my webpack settings. This includes writing ES2017 code.

The goal is to work on both the backend (Laravel) and the frontend (Vue) and communicate between both apps and have both projects in one development tree.

Where do I put the vuejs files and all the webpack stuff to and which additional settings do I need to set and where?

Thanks for any help and ideas.